# How do I get PagerDefault queries to work correctly with Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm running the following code:

```
$query = db_select('taxonomy_index', 'ti')
  ->fields('ti', array('nid'))
  ->condition('ti.tid', $term->tid)
  ->condition('n.status', 1);

$query->join('node', 'n', 'n.nid = ti.nid');

$query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(2);

$nids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
```

but the pager does not work: every item from the query is returned, as if the call to PagerDefault is completely ignored. I am outputting theme('pager') further down in the output so that's not the problem.

This is not the only example of this failure that I have, in several other projects similar queries also bring back the full number of results every time.

I've read all the documentation, it seems to work sometimes and not other times. Anyone got any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not relevant *when* you call `extend()`.

The only thing that is important is that you use the new object returned by `extend()`. The reason for this is that `extend()` creates a new object which wrappes the current object (Decorator pattern).

So, you need to use `$query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')`, like you do in your answer (combined with other calls).

Answer (score 9):

It is not working because you have to do

```
$query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(2);
```